# Excel VBA DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet not transferring numeric/date values to Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, excel

I have written a macro that transfers a Worksheet to an Access database, however it will not add the values in the columns which store phone numbers and dates, respectively.

**Problem 1 (ignore):** In Access, the PhoneNumber field Data Type is a number. When I change the DataType to Short Text, then the phone numbers successfully transfer to the Access Database. I figured that the PhoneNumber column in Excel was storing data as a string rather than a number, so I added some code to convert it to a number, but that didn't help. **EDIT:** I am now storing phone numbers as Short Text data types.

**Problem 2:** The other column that will not transfer values is the "DateProcessed" column which reflects the date added. I have double checked that both the format and value are being stored as Date. 
**EDIT:** I'm an idiot and wasn't importing the Date Processed column which was in Column R.

Code to Convert Phone Numbers to numbers

```
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Range("C2:C" & lastRow).Select    

On Error Resume Next
For Each xCell In Selection
    xCell.Value = CDec(xCell.Value)
    xCell.NumberFormat = "0"
Next xCell
On Error GoTo 0
```

Code to Transfer Spreadsheet to Access

```
Dim acc As New Access.Application

acc.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\Users\Benjamin\Documents\Database1.accdb"    '
acc.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
        acImport, _
        acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
        "CallLog", _
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName, _
        True, _
        "A1:Q" & lastRow
acc.CloseCurrentDatabase
acc.Quit
Set acc = Nothing
```

Comment: It seems to me that you *should* be storing the phone numbers as text values in your database. Why do you want to store them as numeric values?

Comment: @GordThompson I hadn't thought of that. Why store phone numbers as text if they are numbers?

Comment: Ask the opposite question: why store phone numbers as actual numbers? Numeric datatype is useful if you want to perform arithmetic on phone numbers.  So what do you want ... average phone number, total, standard deviation, absolute value?

Comment: @HansUp Good point, I guess I hadn't thought about it that way. Well then I guess my question is no longer important, although I still can't seem to figure out why my code above didn't work.

Comment: "Phone numbers" aren't really "numbers" in the arithmetic sense, they're actually more like email addresses. They only use the digits 0 through 9 because those were the only real "characters" that the terminal (telephone) had on its user interface (rotary dial first, then keypad).

Comment: @GordThompson Thanks, I have changed the Access database to store that data as Short Text. I still have an issue though with another column that captures the date added to the spreadsheet, which isn't transferring to the Access Db. I will edit the question

Answer (score 0):

With your conversion code, you are setting the value of each cell as a number, but Excel may still have the cell formatted as Text, which can cause problems.  Try adding `xCell.NumberFormat = "0"` to your `For` loop.  This will ensure that the format of each cell is set as a number.

Comment: Gave that a try, but it still didn't transfer the phone number column. Strange, no? All the values in the column have been converted to a number and formatted as a number. Unless there is something somewhere else in the macro that is causing this issue ...